# How to compare two 3d coordinates in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, coordinate-systems

I have a vector of 3d coordinates which needs to be checked for upper vale in a grid of 3d coordinates

```
#vector
vec=[(.033,-.22,.98),(.5,-.9,.0029),(-.77,-.01,-.092),(.5,.2,.0029)]

#grid
x1 = np.linspace(-1,1,10)
y1 = np.linspace(-1,1,10)
z1 = np.linspace(-1,1,10)
```

Im using this code which is clearly wrong, because its just comparing the first x coordinate only and not the rest of y,z

```
ctr=0
for v in vec:
    for i in x1:
        for j in y1:
            for k in z1:
                if ctr==0:
                    temp=(i,j,k)
                    ctr+=1
                    continue
                else:
                    #print temp, "to" ,i,j
                    temp2=(i,j,k)
                    if temp<=v<=temp2:
                        print "low,high",temp, temp2
                    temp=(i,j,k)
                    ctr+=1
===WRONG OUTPUT======
low,high (-0.052631578947368474, 1.0, 1.0) (0.052631578947368363, -1.0, -1.0) 
low,high (0.47368421052631571, 1.0, 1.0) (0.57894736842105265, -1.0, -1.0) 
low,high (-0.78947368421052633, 1.0, 1.0) (-0.68421052631578949, -1.0, -1.0) 
low,high (0.47368421052631571, 1.0, 1.0) (0.57894736842105265, -1.0, -1.0)
```

Ive pasted a 2d grid here (3d will follow the same logic). So we start iterating the grid from cell (0,0) in a serial order. As you can see the lower & higher coordinate for point v 
[image]

Comment: Can you define more clearly what you mean by upper value? distance from origin? largest distance between 2 of the coordinates given?

Comment: @jeffcarey added a description pic